# Use Arraylist (java / android) in PHP (laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel

I'm building an API (with the Laravel framework) for my Android App. I'm sending the following array from the app to the API:

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

I want to process every entry of the array by looping through the array and processing each entry. How do i get this done?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: send it in any format and process it on android. For example xml, json, yaml etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data to API as json.
Then retrieve this data in the laravel:

```
$inputData = json_decode($request->getContent());
$inputDataArray = json_decode(json_encode($inputData), true);
```

then iterate:

```
for each($inputDataArray as $item){
    //DO PROCESSING OF ITEM ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You even gave me more then i needed :)